# Freeradius running debug mode libssl version mismatch

Tags: freeradius

I'm trying to build and install Freeradius version 3.0.8 using [these instructions](http://wiki.freeradius.org/building/Debian%20and%20Ubuntu). But after starting Freeradius in debug mode using command `radiusd -X` shows following error.

```
libssl version mismatch.  built: 1000207f linked: 1000114f
```

I tried removing libssl-dev and reinstall, But no luck.

Appreciate any help to resolve this version mismatch error. My os is Ubuntu 16.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're building/installing on the same server you have multiple versions of OpenSSL installed.  When you built the server it found version 1.0.2, when the server runs however, it's linked against 1.0.1.  The server refuses to start because 1.0.2 and 1.0.1 are ABI incompatible and allowing the server to start may cause subtle errors in any code that called OpenSSL.

As a workaround you can use the LD_PRELOAD environmental variable to specify the path to OpenSSL 1.0.2.

If you're building/installing on two different systems you must ensure both systems have the same version of OpenSSL.